# Java client receives from C server, but C server does't receive from Java Client

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp

I've created a simple server in C and a simple client in Java as a stand-in for functionality in a larger application. I'm able to connect the client to the server, and the client is able to receive a message from the server. However, when I try to receive a message from the client in the server, I get nothing. After some research, I'm fairly confident that my client should be working, so I feel like the issue must be on the receiving side, but I'm really not sure what the problem is, as I've used basically the same C code for other applications without issue. If someone could help me figure out the issue I would be very appreciative.

Here is the simple Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost",9000);
        BufferedReader inputBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        String line = inputBuffer.readLine();
        System.out.println("From server : "+line);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        String toSend = "I am sending you a message. I sure hope you get it.\n";

        out.write(toSend.toCharArray());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

And here is my C code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int port = 9000;
int buffer_size = 256;

int sock;
int new_sock;
socklen_t client_len;
struct sockaddr_in server_address;
struct sockaddr_in client_address;
char* line_status;
int len;
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sock < 0)
{
    printf("Couldn't open socket.\n");
}

bzero((char*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server_address.sin_port = htons(port);

int status = bind(sock, 
                  (struct sockaddr *) & server_address, 
                  sizeof(server_address));

if(status < 0)
{
    printf("Error binding to socket.\n");
}

listen(sock, 5);
client_len = sizeof(client_address);
printf("Listening for clients on port %d...\n", port);
new_sock = accept(sock, 
                  (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, 
                  &client_len);

if(new_sock < 0)
{
    printf("Error accepting connection.\n");
}else
{
    printf("Connected\n");
    char outbuffer[] = "123456789\n";

    int write_stat = write(new_sock, outbuffer, 10);
    printf("wrote message to socket\n");

    char buffer[buffer_size];
    int read_stat = 0;
    while(read_stat <= 0)
    {
        char c;
        read_stat = read(port,buffer, buffer_size);
        if(read_stat >0)
        {
            printf("read_stat = %d\n",read_stat);
            printf("received message: %s\n",buffer);
        }

    }
    printf("done\n");

}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Any `read()` or `recv()` call that doesn't store the result into a variable and/or isn't followed by testing for zero and -1 separately is not written correctly.

Comment: Formatting/indentation, plus what @EJP says.

Comment: and, (inevitable?), 'printf("received message: %s\n",buffer);' - use of a call that requires a NUL terminated string on a buffer that is not securely NUL_terminated, (which could have been avoided if you had fully and correctly handled the result returned by the read, as posted by EJP).

Comment: Well it should be `printf("received message %.*s\n", read_stat, buffer)`. No need to null-terminate anything. And `read_stat` is poorly named for a count variable. @MartinJames

Comment: @EJP that is an alternative, sure:)

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to read from a "port-number"

```
... = read(port,buffer, buffer_size);
```

but from the accepted socket

```
... = read(new_sock, buffer, buffer_size);
```

**Hint**: *If* you'd added complete error checking *and* handling to the call to `read()` you'd have immediately stumbled over this bug. Error checking is debugging for free!

---

A note unrelated to your particular issue: From that the code uses `socklen_t` I conclude you are *not* on Windows. So `read()` and `write()` *most likely* return `ssize_t` *not* `int`.